# Adobe Experience Manager WorkBench Check out/in Issue

Tags: sql-server, adobe, aem, workbench, livecycle

Shortly I ve Windows Server 2012 R2, AEM Forms(6.2), SQLServer(2014) and Workbench(6.2) in same server. At first when i install and configure all of them, i can check out or in my applications from Workbench succesfully. However After my software team executes some scripts at Database, we can not check in/out from workbench. The worst thing when i click check out, workbench gives any error. any log. on event log or server application. It gives nothing and don't do my transaction. I saw at forums some people have same issue but nobody writes solution.

Please if any one knows the solution, share with us. What's wrong with my workbench? what to do fix this issue?

Comment: What scripts do your software team execute?

Comment: update [AdobeDB1].[dbo].[tb_sc_service] set security_enabled= 0
update  [AdobeDB1].[dbo].[tb_sc_service_configuration] set run_as_configuration = 'RUN_AS_SYSTEM'

Comment: So your software team screws around with the Livecycle database and then you are surprised when things stop working. The correct answer is to tell them to stop doing that.

Answer (score 1):

The query that your software team ran turns off security on every single LiveCycle service and makes them run as the system user. This includes the services used by Workbench and is very bad. Some of the services rely on knowing who is logged in to operate correctly. In particular, how can LiveCycle know who has checked in/out a resource if the service always runs as system?

Your best bet is to restore the LiveCycle database - or at least the `tb_sc_service_configuration` table to be where it was before you ran the script.

If you need to remove security on individual services, you should do it through the admin console, but only do it for your processes. Never do it for systems services unless the Adobe documentation says it is OK.

Answer (score 0):

As [JeremyP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/169346/jeremyp) pointed out, modifying the Adobe database directly is a bad idea.  The database should be treated as a black box that is only manipulated by Adobe code (either by doing things in the Adobe tools or making calls to Adobe APIs).

You can either make security changes manually through the adminui (as he indicates, which is the most common way of doing it) or programatically using the Adobe client APIs.  See the following links for sample code that uses the APIs:

Removing Security - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/10.0/ProgramLC/WS624e3cba99b79e12e69a9941333732bac8-7f35.html

Setting the runAs user - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/10.0/ProgramLC/WS624e3cba99b79e12e69a9941333732bac8-7f38.html

My company, [4Point](http://www.4point.com/), offers AEM Forms consulting services.  We have an in-house [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/) library that wraps the code above to automate this (and other) common tasks that are typically required when deploying (and redeploying) AEM Forms solutions.  It can be included as part of a consulting engagement.